Sorted table of data from elsewhere in a document
I am trying to provide a sorted overview of some data points at the start of my document, e.g.:
+-----------+-----+---------------------+
| height    | age | description         |
+-----------+-----+---------------------+
| 1.75      | 23  | some text goes here |
+-----------+-----+---------------------+
| 1.83      | 21  | other text          |
+-----------+-----+---------------------+
| (...)
+-----------+-----+---------------------+

(can't post the actual table, confidential data)
So I'd like to set these values in various paragraphs where the cases are described. At the start of the document I have a simple table that lists these values, sorted high-to-low by age, and again, sorted by height. I currently update that manually as I go along, but that's a lot of work and error-prone...
I've looked at building an array and then using arraysort but that doesn't seem able to sort multi-dimensional arrays (and I'm not sure that will work on a second pass, as the overview table is before the definition of the data in the document).
Maybe I am looking at it wrong, and am just trying to do a very custom \tableofcontents?
Any help appreciated!
edit example document:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}

This document discusses some cases that will go into a lot of detail about age related to height.

Here's a summary:

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|l|}
    \hline \textit{height} & \textit{age} & \textit{description} \\

    % a lot of data follows that is defined elsewhere in the document, e.g.:

    \hline 1.75 & 23 & some text to describe the case \\
    \hline 1.83 & 21 & some text to describe the case \\
    \hline 2.01 & 29 & some text to describe the case \\\hline
\end{tabular}

The same data, sorted by age:

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|l|}
    \hline \textit{height} & \textit{age} & \textit{description} \\

    % same data, different order:

    \hline 1.83 & 21 & some text to describe the case \\
    \hline 1.75 & 23 & some text to describe the case \\
    \hline 2.01 & 29 & some text to describe the case \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{Details}

\subsection{Case 1}

Describing the case of an individual aged 29 years. She is 2.01 metres tall.

% here I would like to define the values, something like
%   \setvalues{case1,29,2.01,some text to describe the case}

\subsection{Case 2}

Describing the case of an individual aged 21 years. He is 1.75 metres tall.

% here I would like to define the values, something like
%   \setvalues{case1,29,2.01,some text to describe the case}

\subsection{Case 3}

etc...

\end{document}


it's possible but you should provide a test document but note that mostly latex does not sort, sorted bibliographies use bibtex or biber, sorted indexes use makeindex. Also make it clearer what you want to sort on. If it's just numeric data in the first column, it's not too hard, if you want language sensitive lexigraphic sorting of free text then it's much harder

Thanks for your reply. It's hard to provide a test document, because I now just do it by hand so there's really no bug to fix or something, I just don't know the best way to approach the problem. But I'll give it a go.

You've set the xetex tag -- does this mean that you employ XeLaTeX to compile your document? If so, might you be willing and able to employ LuaLaTeX instead? Please advise.

I'm now using XeLaTeX but am willing to consider LuaLaTeX (hope that doesn't break other things in the document)

I'm not sure how your data looks like and what you actually want to do with it, but maybe have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool It is very powerful.

Does this answer your question? Sorting Table Column

Partially, yes. But I need to put the table before the data is defined.

Nice problem.
The idea is to save the data in the .aux file, so it can be retrieved at the next LaTeX run. So \setvalues{<age>}{<height>}{<desc>} is saved as
\VALUE{<age>}{<height>}{<desc>}{<subsection>}

I also add the subsection number, maybe you want to use it.
When the .aux file is read at the beginning of the run, the values are stored in a sequence that can be used “raw” or sorted according to decreasing age and decreasing height.
The sorting is done by comparing the age multiplied by 1000 plus the height.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setvalues}{mmm}
 {
  \iow_shipout:ce {@auxout} { \exp_not:n { \VALUE{#1}{#2}{#3} }{\thesubsection} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\VALUE}{mmmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_koek_values_seq { {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PRINT}{mmmm}{#1 & #2 & #3}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printunsortedsummary}{}
 {
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__koek_values_out_seq \g_koek_values_seq { \PRINT##1 }
  \__koek_values_print:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printsortedsummary}{}
 {
  \__koek_values_sort:
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__koek_values_out_seq \l__koek_values_tmp_seq { \PRINT##1 }
  \__koek_values_print:
 }

\seq_new:N \g_koek_values_seq
\seq_new:N \l__koek_values_tmp_seq
\seq_new:N \l__koek_values_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__koek_values_sort:
 {
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l__koek_values_tmp_seq \g_koek_values_seq
  \seq_sort:Nn \l__koek_values_tmp_seq
   {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { \__koek_values_compute:nnnn ##1 } > { \__koek_values_compute:nnnn ##2 }
     {
      \sort_return_same:
     }
     {
      \sort_return_swapped:
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__koek_values_compute:nnnn { #1*1000+#2 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__koek_values_print:
 {
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}
  \hline
  \textit{Height} & \textit{Age} & \textit{Description} \\ \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l__koek_values_out_seq { \\ \hline }
  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}

This document discusses some cases that will go into a 
lot of detail about age related to height.

Here's a summary:
\begin{center}
\printunsortedsummary
\end{center}

The same data, sorted by age:
\begin{center}
\printsortedsummary
\end{center}

\section{Details}

\subsection{Case 1}
\setvalues{29}{2.01}{some text to describe the case}

Describing the case of an individual aged 29 years. She is 2.01 metres tall.

\subsection{Case 2}
\setvalues{21}{1.75}{some text to describe the case}

Describing the case of an individual aged 21 years. He is 1.75 metres tall.

\subsection{Case 3}
\setvalues{21}{1.85}{some text to describe the case}

etc...

\end{document}


If you change \PRINT into
\NewDocumentCommand{\PRINT}{mmmm}{#1 & #2 & #3~(#4)}

so you can refer to the subsection, you get

If you want decreasing age and increasing height, you can modify one definition into
\cs_new:Nn \__koek_values_compute:nnnn { #1*1000+10-#2 }

and the sorted table will become

In order to add the subsection number, do the same change as before.
Finally, if you load \usepackage{booktabs} and modify the table printing command into
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__koek_values_print:
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccl@{}}
  \toprule
  \textit{Height} & \textit{Age} & \textit{Description} \\ \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l__koek_values_out_seq { \\ }
  \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

you get a much nicer output.

Important note
If you're running a TeX Live distribution prior to the 2023 release, replace
\iow_shipout:ce

with
\iow_shipout:cx

or, maybe better, add
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_shipout:Nn {ce}

just after \ExplSyntaxOn.

This is fantastic, thank you very much!
I'm getting an error though when feeding this to XeLaTeX:
! Undefined control sequence.
\setvalues code #1#2#3->\iow_shipout:ce
{@auxout}{\exp_not:n {\VALUE {#1}{#2...
l.79 ...{29}{2.01}{some text to describe the case}

Looks like it's failing the first time the command \setvalues is called at line 79. No values are written to the .aux file

@MarkKoek I guess you have an outdated version of LaTeX. You can replace \iow_shipout:ce with \iow_shipout:cx and it should behave. I added a warning at the end. However, you should upgrade your TeX distribution.

That works, thanks!
